# Mongodb get count of arrayitems over all collection items

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a mongodb-collection like this:

```
{
    _id: 123,
    name: 'some name',
    category: 17,
    sizes: ['XS', 'S', 'XL']
},
{
    _id: 124,
    name: 'another name',
    category: 17,
    sizes: ['S', 'L', '2XL']
}
```

I need two different approaches. First one: How many items per size are available in a specific category?

```
{
    17: {
        XS: 0,
        S:  19,
        M:  100
    },
    39: {
        XS: 5,
        ...
    }
}
```

A solution, which just shows *if* an item in the size is available would also be possible:

```
{
    17: {
        XS: false,
        S:  true,
        M:  true,
        ...
    },
    39: {
        XS: true,
        ...
    }
}
```

Second problem: I need the same, but after performing a full-text-search on a name.

I've tried to [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) over the fields, but I'm a bit lost on how to perform that on the array.

Any help appreciated.

---

**Update**:

With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13076334/898999), I'm one step closer:

```
db.so.aggregate(
    [
        // First, filter by name or something else
        // this could also include the category
        { 
            $match: {
                'name': {
                    $regex: /other.*/i
                }
            }
        },

        // explode the sizes-array into single documents
        { '$unwind': '$sizes' },

        // group and count
        { '$group': {
            '_id': '$sizes',
            'count': { '$sum': 1 }
        }}
    ]
)
```

Still missing: do this by category

Comment: You can do something like this:
[
  {
    '$unwind': '$sizes'
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'size': '$sizes',
        'category': '$category'
      },
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }
]
to generate documents like:
{
    "_id" : {
        "size" : "XS",
        "category" : 17
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some example data that I inserted:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 123,
    "name" : "some name",
    "category" : 17,
    "sizes" : [ 
        "XS", 
        "S", 
        "XL"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 124,
    "name" : "another name",
    "category" : 17,
    "sizes" : [ 
        "S", 
        "L", 
        "2XL"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 125,
    "name" : "name",
    "category" : 35,
    "sizes" : [ 
        "S", 
        "L", 
        "2XL"
    ]
}
```

## Use case 1

What you seem to want in your first use case, is grouping by sizes AND category. You can actually group by multiple keys and here is an example:

```
db.so.aggregate([
    // add your match here...
    {
        '$unwind': '$sizes' // flatten your array
    },
    // group and count
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                sizes: '$sizes',
                category: '$category'
            }, // group by both sizes and category
            'count': {
                '$sum': 1
            },

        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$category', // group by category now
            sizeCount: { // create an array that includes the size and the count for that size
                $push: { 
                    size: "$sizes",
                    count: "$count"
                }
            }

        }
    }
])
```

This pipeline would create this result:

```
{
    "_id" : 17,
    "sizeCount" : [ 
        {
            "size" : "2XL",
            "count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "size" : "XS",
            "count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "size" : "S",
            "count" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "size" : "XL",
            "count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "size" : "L",
            "count" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

would that be acceptable for you?

## Use case 2

Now regarding your second use case how do you want to group sizes that don't even exist for this category?
But in general you can manipulate your result by using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

So in the same example if you apply this pipeline:

```
db.so.aggregate([
    // add your match here ...
    {
        '$unwind': '$sizes' // flatten your array
    },
    // group and count
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                sizes: '$sizes',
                category: '$category'
            }, // group by both sizes and category
            'count': {
                '$sum': 1
            },

        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            _id: 0,
            'count': {
                $cond: [{
                    $eq: ["$count", 1.0]
                }, "Limited", "Many"]
            },
            category: "$_id.category",
            sizes: "$_id.sizes"
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$category',
            sizeCount: {
                $push: {
                    size: "$sizes",
                    count: "$count"
                }
            }

        }
    }
])
```

It would produce the following result (one example):

```
{
    "_id" : 17,
    "sizeCount" : [ 
        {
            "size" : "2XL",
            "count" : "Limited"
        }, 
        {
            "size" : "XS",
            "count" : "Limited"
        }, 
        {
            "size" : "S",
            "count" : "Many"
        }, 
        {
            "size" : "XL",
            "count" : "Limited"
        }, 
        {
            "size" : "L",
            "count" : "Limited"
        }
    ]
}
```

So basically in this line `$cond: [{$eq: ["$count", 1.0]}, "Limited", "Many"]}`
we say that if the `count` field is only 1.0, then the shirts for that size are Limited, otherwise we have Many. You can apply any comparison operator, so you can also do things like: `$cond: [{$lte: ["$count", 2.0]}, "Limited", "Many"]}`

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Projection will be added soon.

You can

`unwind` -> `group on category and size` -> `group on category and push` -> `project`

Please refer to the below query. This will give a result without any projection. I will add the projection to match your requirement soon.

```
var group_by_category_and_sizes = { 
  "$group": { 
    "_id": { 
        "category": "$category", 
        "size": "$sizes"
      }, 
      "count": { 
        "$sum": 1 
      } 
    } 
  }

var group_by_category_and_push = {
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "category": "$_id.category"
    }, 
    "combine": {
      "$push": { "size": "$_id.size", "count": "$count" }
    }
  }
}

db.clothings.aggregate([{ "$unwind": "$sizes" }, group_by_category_and_sizes, group_by_category_and_push])
```

For documents

`{ name: 'some name', category: 17, sizes: ['XS', 'S', 'XL'] }`

`{ name: 'another name', category: 17, sizes: ['S', 'L', '2XL'] }`

`{ name: 'another name', category: 18, sizes: ['M', 'S', 'L'] }`

this will produce

```
{
    "_id": {
        "category": 18
    },
    "combine": [{
        "size": "L",
        "count": 1
    }, {
        "size": "S",
        "count": 1
    }, {
        "size": "M",
        "count": 1
    }]
} {
    "_id": {
        "category": 17
    },
    "combine": [{
        "size": "2XL",
        "count": 1
    }, {
        "size": "S",
        "count": 2
    }, {
        "size": "XL",
        "count": 1
    }, {
        "size": "L",
        "count": 1
    }, {
        "size": "XS",
        "count": 1
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can pretty much get to the exact output document you suggested:

```
db.so.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$sizes" // flatten the sizes array
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: { // group by both category and sizes
            category: "$category",
            size: "$sizes"
        },
        count: {
           $sum: 1 // count number of documents per bucket
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.category", // second grouping to get entries per category
        sizes: {
           $push: { k: "$_id.size", v: "$count" } // create an array of key/value pairs which we will need in this exact shape in the next stage
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "magic": {
            $arrayToObject: // transform the key/value pair we generate below into a document
            [[{
                // the $substr is a hack to transform the numerical category (e.g. 17) 
                // into a string (not nice, probably not supported but working for now...)
                // which is needed for the above $arrayToObject to work
                k: { $substr: [ "$_id", 0, -1 ] }, 
                v: {
                    $arrayToObject: "$sizes" // turn the key/value pairs we created in the previous pipeline stage into a document
                }
            }]]
        }
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$magic" // promote our "magic" field to the document root
    }
})
```

Please note that while this gives you the right output, I would not necessarily suggest going down that route since the aggregation pipeline is pretty hefty with quite some magic built into it for very little measurable benefit. So if you can accept an output structure like the one suggested by @Alex P. then this will certainly be easier to understand and maintain and faster as well.

With respect to your second scenario: You can add any number of preliminary $match stages before the `$unwind` stage to filter out any superfluous data.